# Fluent NHibernate HasOne + HasMany with same child class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I have a class **Employer** which contains a collection of **UserGroup** but it also has another **UserGroup** called *Administrators*

the idea is that an employer always has one administrators group with all permissions etc. But they can create arbitrary groups as they see fit.

```
  public class Employer
  {
     public virtual UserGroup Administrators { get; set; }
     public virtual IList<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
  }
```

The Mappings are:

```
mapping.HasOne(x => x.Administrators)
       .PropertyRef(g => g.Employer)
       .Constrained() //Lazy load
       .Cascade.All();


mapping.HasMany(x => x.UserGroups).Inverse();
```

The problem is, when a query for an Employer is made, it always returns more than one row for groups, e.g. *Admins + Managers etc...*

Is it possible to use the same Type in for two purposes on one class like above?? 
What other alternatives do I have to express this?

Cheers...

Answer (score 2):

You can map the same class in multiple ways by using entity names. Will try to post example later.

Comment: An example of entity name usage in a plain XML mapping file is given here: http://www.fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/. Fluent NHibernate supports entity names from version 1.1 onwards.

Comment: And if you want to map the same entity class twice to the same table, besides defining a unique entity-name for each mapping of this entity class, you could define a where attribute (ChildWhere in Fluent NHibernate) on each class mapping to filter out the rows to which the mapping applies.